# SwiftUI Observable Object returning stale data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I am pretty new to SwiftUI and I am messing around with a login API with Flask. I am using ObservableObject as BindableObject is deprecated.

```
class Auth: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()

    var authenticated = false {
        willSet{
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    func verify(username : String, password : String){

        guard let url = URL(string: "MyAPIURL")
            else {return}

        let bodyFormat : [String:String] = ["Username":username,"Password":password]
        let body = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyFormat)

        var request = URLRequest(url:url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = body

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data,response,error) in
            guard let data = data else {return}

            let decodedData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(UserLoginData.self, from: data)

            print(decodedData.Status)
            if(decodedData.Status == "Success"){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.authenticated = true
                }
            }
            else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.authenticated = false
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

In the main view I have

```
@ObservedObject var authenticator = Auth()
self.authenticator.verify(username: self.username, password: self.password)
print(authenticator.authenticated)
```

I am printing it to check the value. Now the problem is, the server will return the "Success" response but when i do `print(authenticator.authenticated)` it prints out the older data. When I press the Login button twice it works as it gets the previous data that was assigned.

Thank you for any help!!

EDIT: One thing that I have noticed is that the `print(authenticator.authenticated)`  line is being called before the `authenticator.authenticated` line and thus it will return the last value it was set to.

Comment: If proposed solution does not work for you then the reason is also in some other not provided code.

Answer (score -1):

just move your print to here:

```
print(decodedData.Status)
        if(decodedData.Status == "Success"){
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.authenticated = true
//-> print here
            }
        }
        else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.authenticated = false
//-> print here

            }
        }
```